# How to convert to laravel from express js?

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, express

I have a few lines of code which is written in express js, I want to convert into the laravel code,

```html
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    var jsonResponse = [];
    jsonResponse.push({ "text": "Hi. 3 is a lucky number..." });
    res.send(jsonResponse);
});
```

Is there anyway? Please guide me.
Here is my tried , don't know correct or not.

```html
    public function json_test(){
      $message =["text" => "Hi.  is a lucky number..."];
      return $message;
    }
```

Comment: I answered your question. Please check it out and upvote it if it was helpful. Mark it correct if answers your question. I hope I helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Long story short**

I think everything is correct. You just have to change your return value to be a json response.

**A bit more detailed**

You must first define a route in api.php:

```
Route::get('/some/url', 'ExampleController@jsonTest');
```

Next you must define a controller and inside the controller the functions that you need:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    public function jsonTest(){
      $message =["text" => "Hi.  is a lucky number..."];
      return response()->json($message);
    }
}
```

In case you don't need an entire controller for this you can simply place the functionality in the api.php file like so:

```
Route::get('/some/url', function () {
     $message =["text" => "Hi.  is a lucky number..."];
     return response()->json($message);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually i am trying to follow this  tutorial, and its not working yet, in laravel point of view , its working the same, but in the messenger, its not pushing back the json . do you have anyidea? https://community.chatfuel.com/t/add-serverside-logic-to-your-bot-with-just-10-lines-of-javascript/3543?u=luca

Comment: I will try to help @ThanHtutOo but I need a more detailed question. Could you post it as a separate question with more details and code examples / data output? Could you also please upvote my answer? It will help a lot. Thanks

Comment: @ThanHtutOo you can tag me on the other question so I can see it if you post it.